# What's the best way to check the state of a certain bit, in a 32-bit word architecture?

Tags: assembly, bit

In a university lab, we are using a TI6713 processor for signal processing purposes. I have often found myself in a position where I need to do an action based on a flag bit located in one of the 32-bit registers. Some of these flags trigger interrupts when they are changed, whereas some do not.

So far I have been able to do my work by shifting left and right till the bit of interest is the least significant and sign extended. For example:

```
SHL A0, 14, A0 ;Shift the 17th bit 14 times left
SHR A0, 31, A0 ;Shift the bit 31 times right
[A0] B LOOP ;Branch if it's not 0
```

where A0 contains the flag bit 17. The problem with this is that I need to alter the register, or use more registers (which might already be in use). Also the amount of shifting I have to do has to be calculated, and although it's fairly straightforward, I'm usually in no state of mind to perform it. The instruction guide is vast, and so far I have not been able to find an instruction that fits my needs.

Is there a better/more robust way to perform this task?

Comment: Can't you place a single bit mask in a processor register then `AND` it with the control register?

Comment: @WeatherVane That. Is a very fine idea i wish i had thought myself. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm totally new to the *TMS320C6713x* and its *VelociTI* architecture but usually DSP have instructions to handle bit fields.
In this case I've found these one:

- `ext` extracts a bit field and sign extends it in a 32-bit register.
- `extu` same as above but zero extends it.
- `clr` clear a bit field.
- `set` set a bit field.

The `ext/u` instructions work exactly like your code (a left shift followed by a right shift) to the point that the immediate operands are the same.

A possible code to extract the bit 17 (note that bit 17 is the 18th bit) could be:

```
EXT A0, 14, 31, A0
[A0] B LOOP
```

Note this code is untested.

`CLR` and `SET` can be useful to clear and set a set of bits respectively.
The operand are more straightforward then the `ext/u` ones, they are the LSb and the MSb (both inclusive) of the bit field.

```
CLR A0, 0, 3, A0   ;Clear the lowest nibble of A0
SET A0, 4, 7, A0   ;Set the high nibble of the lowest byte of A0
```

As suggested in the comment an `AND` will also do but if I've understood the datasheet correctly you can only use a register-register or a register-immediate AND, where the immediate is *5 bits*.
So for extracting bits above bit 4 you need to pre-load a register.

Comment: Thank you for your full and clear answer, Ill be using it from here on!

Comment: @VlassisFo Glad to help. Be careful with the code as this is the first time I see a TI6713